# Why doesn't this alternative method work? Chance of getting four of a kind in a hand of $5$ cards?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

Please note: This is not a [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1819001/probability-of-being-dealt-four-of-a-kind-in-a-set-of-5-cards) since it is asking about an alternative method of solving the question

> What is the probability of getting four of a kind in a hand of $5$ cards from a standard $52$ card deck?

I am trying to solve this problem using permutations (as opposed to [combinations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1819001/probability-of-being-dealt-four-of-a-kind-in-a-set-of-5-cards)). The sample space is the set of distinguishable hands of $5$, and its cardinality is $P(52, 5)$. This will be our denominator.

Now, we need to count the number of possible hands which contain four of a kind. Let's consider a subset of the sample space which contains one complete kind, say $4$ kings. There are $5!$ possible hands which will have four of a kind of king. There are $13$ kinds, so there are $5! \cdot 13$ possible hands which contain four of a kind. Therefore our probability is $\dfrac {5! \cdot 13}{P(52, 5)}$. However, this is wrong. My answer seems to be greatly underestimating the probability. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There are $5!$ possible hands which will have four of a kind of king.

This is wrong. A hand with five cards and four kings will have four kings and some other card. There are $48$ possibilities for the other card, so there are $5!\cdot 48$ possibilities of hands with four kinds.

Thus, our answer should be:
$$\frac{5!\cdot 48\cdot 13}{_{52}P_5}$$

Comment: Note that this probability is the same [as the probability described here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1819015/307483).

Comment: I'm not sure if this is because I'm new to counting, but it seems like counting problems are the easiest to make mistakes in. On so many problems I was 100% sure my answer is right, only to find out I undercounter or overcounted.

Comment: @Ovi I am a high school mathlete and I agree with this. There are so many times I have overlooked something in combinatorics problems, but over time, if you see similar problems multiple times, you learn from past mistakes and don't overlook things as much anymore. However, I still make a lot of mistakes on combinatorics problems I've never seen before.

Comment: That is why students are asked to practice on many *apparently* simple exercises.  They are never as easy as first assumed; but the effort pays off eventually.  Persevere!

Answer (score 2):

For the favorable cases, you have to choose the repeated kind, choose one of the $48$ cards that are not of that kind (which is where you went wrong), and order the five chosen cards.  Therefore, the numerator should be 
$$13 \cdot 48 \cdot 5!$$

Answer (score 1):

Recall that $~{^n{\rm P}_r} := {^n{\rm C}_r}\cdot r!~$ is the count of ways to select $r$ from $n$ distinct items *and* to arrange those selected items.

This is okay when making one selection and arranging those items.   Such as the probability space; which is generated by making a selection and arrangement of $5$ from $52$ items.   That is counted by: $$~^{52}{\rm P}_5$$

However the favoured space is made by *three* selections and *one* arrangement of all items selected.  The task is to select $1$ from $13$ faces, $4$ from $4$ suits, select $1$ from $48$ other cards, and to arrange the $5$ selected items.   This is counted by: $${{^{13}{\rm C}_1}\cdot{^4{\rm C}_4}\cdot{^{48}{\rm C}_1}\cdot5!}$$

These outcomes are all equi-probable, so the probability we seek is the ratio:

$$\dfrac{{^{13}{\rm C}_1}\cdot{^4{\rm C}_4}\cdot{^{48}{\rm C}_1}\cdot5!}{^{52}{\rm P}_5}$$

Or simply: $~13\cdot 48\cdot 5! \big/\, {^{52}{\rm P}_5}$

---

Of course, we may expand out the denominator to obtain:
$$\require{cancel}\dfrac{{^{13}{\rm C}_1}\cdot{^4{\rm C}_4}\cdot{^{48}{\rm C}_1}\cdot\cancel{5!}}{^{52}{\rm C}_5\cdot \cancel{5!}}$$

Answer (score 0):

You are counting permutations, not combinations, so there are
$$5!\times1\times1\times1\times1\times48=576,$$
hands with $4$ kings.