# Probability of getting 4 aces while drawing 6 cards.

Tags: probability, card-games

Drawing 6 cards from a standard deck of 52 cards, what is the probability of getting 4 aces?

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1819015) explains how to calculate the odds of a getting *any* 4-of-a-kind in a 5-card draw. I was hoping it would be obvious how to adjust that solution to solve my problem, but I'm not confident that I understand it well enough.

Given that there are 13 possible 4-of-a-kinds, and I am concerned with only 1 of them, I would assume the odds are 13 times less likely than simply drawing a 4-of-a-kind, but that's where I run out of steam.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{{4\choose4}{48\choose 2}}{52\choose6}$$

Note this is $\frac1{13}$ of the   (fairly easy) adaptation from your link to $6$ choices.

Comment: The answer given by user247327 doesn't seem to match this one. Also, this isn't 1/13th of the answer given in the example I linked. By my calculation, this is 3/13 of that answer. Can you explain how you arrive at this answer?

Comment: The two answers match.   I checked it.  I adjusted the solution for the fact that $6$ choices are made rather than $5$.

Answer (score 2):

There are 52 cards, 4 of them aces.  The probability the **first** card drawn is an ace is 4/52= 1/13.  There are then 51 cards, 3 of them aces.  The probability the **second** card drawn is an ace is 3/51= 1/17.  There are then 50 cards, 2 of them aces.  The probability the third card drawn is an ace is 2/50= 1/25.  There are then 49 cards, 1 of them an ace.  The probability the fourth card drawn is 1/49.  After that of course the last two cards **must** be non-aces.  So the probability of "four aces followed by 2 non-aces, in **that** order" is (1/13)(1/17)(1/25)(1/49).  There are a total of 6!/(4!(2!)= 15 different orders:  AAAANN, AAANAN, AANAAN, ANAAAN, etc. I will leave to you to show that the probability of "four aces, two non-aces" in **any** of those orders is the same, (1/13)(1/17)(1/25)(1/49), so the probability of "four aces, two non-aces" is 15(1/13)(1/17)(1/25)(1/49).